# register for email address is unique

Tags: php

I want to validate the email address to make sure that it is unique. 
By using the following code, it suppose to check the user input is not empty, is a valid email address and also it is not duplicated 
but my code seem like doesn't work and gave me the following error.
i already go through the question that had been asked by other people but i still cnt solve the problem

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in

I wonder is that my sequence of 'if' statement is wrong or what else?
any help please?

Here is my code

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    $valid = false;
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

    if  (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 

    } if($email != "") {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM email where email='".$email."'");
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    }if($num_rows >= 1){
        $emailErr = "Email already in use";
        $valid =false;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (empty($_POST["email"]))`  See anything wrong?Also you are mixing mysql with mysqli

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo, but you used `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query`. And use `isset()` instead of `empty()`

Comment: oh sry. By the way, i already changed to mysql but still the error is there

Comment: why are you using mysql_* function and some places mysqli_*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/folder/public\_html/folder/folder/login.php on line 18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306038/warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)

Comment: Still using mysql functions? use mysqli_* instead

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result (that is $result) of mysqli_query before passing it to mysqli_num_rows, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score 0):

Make code easily maintainable for future use. I have updated your code, check this solution.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "worldDB");
if (isset($_POST['submit']){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM emails where email='".$email."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows >= 1){
            echo "email already exist";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
            echo "Thank you for Submitting.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.